# count with two where returns 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to count all replies with an image using:
`<%= Reply.where(:post_id => post.id).where(:reply_file_fingerprint => true).count %>`

However this is returning 0

How can I properly count the number of replies that contain an image?

log:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "replies"  WHERE "replies"."post_id" = 1 AND "replies"."reply_file_fingerprint" = 't'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not tell us what your column `reply_file_fingerprint` is, but the name sounds like it is *not* a boolean. You ask the database for rows the the value "t" and probably there are just no rows with the value "t". So the database is correctly returning "0".

If your fingerprint is same kind of hashsum, and it is NULL when there is no image, this you can get all replies with images like this:

```
Reply.where(:post_id => post.id).
    where('reply_file_fingerprint IS NOT NULL').count
```

To use associations like "max" suggested should give you the same result as asking explicitly for the `post_id`.

Comment: In more recent Rails versions, where.not(reply_file_fingerprint: nil).count

Answer (score 1):

Use the associations Luke!

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :replies
end

class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

This will let us do:

```
post.replies.where(reply_file_fingerprint: true).count
```

However this will cause what is known as N+1 query since each post will cause a COUNT query on the replies table.

Instead you may want load it ahead of time with

```
@posts = Post.eager_load(:replies)
             .where(replies: { reply_file_fingerprint: true })
```

And instead of `.count` use the smarter `.size`:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.replies.size %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Also make sure that `reply_file_fingerprint` is a boolean column!

Comment: Already had associations, your first one returned 0, how ever the second worked

Comment: Thats kind of strange.

Comment: is there someway I can add on a -3? so insted of 4 it shows 1?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking - why would you want to do that?

Comment: This should probably be another question, this is for a line saying how many replies have been omitted from being shown (<% replies.last(3).each do |reply| %>)  so I need the total of replies with images -3

Answer (score 0):

Add both filters in a single `.where()`, but that's the same thing as what you have done.

```
<%= Reply.where(:post_id => post.id, :reply_file_fingerprint => true).count %>
```

This would generate an SQL like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM "replies"
  WHERE "replies"."post_id" = ? AND
     "replies"."reply_file_fingerprint" = ?  [["post_id", 123], ["reply_file_fingerprint", "t"]]
```

I guess you just don't have `Reply`s with fingerprints for that specific post id.

Comment: I made sure, there are 4 related replies with fingerprints.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count both conditions at once:

```
Reply.where(:post_id => post.id).group(:reply_file_fingerprint).count
```

This will return a hash using a single query, in which the keys are the values of reply_file_fingerprint found, and the values are the number of occurrences.

e.g.

```
{true => 4, false => 1}
{true => 4}
{false => 1}
{}
```

So:

```
found_hsh = Reply.where(:post_id => post.id).group(:reply_file_fingerprint).count
trues  = found_hsh[true ] || 0
falses = found_hsh[false] || 0
```